# From where can I study more about Dickson polynomials?

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I know some basic bits about this construction as to how they effect permutations of Galois fields. But I want to get some detailed understanding of them. Any references?

Comment: https://www.concours-centrale-supelec.fr/CentraleSupelec/2014/MP/sujets/2012-006.pdf the last part

Comment: Any translation into English? :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some good references. Some books that might help:

- Dickson Polynomials by R. Lidl, G. Turnwald and G. Mullen
- Finite Fields by R. Lidl and H. Niederreiter:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Finite-Fields-Encyclopedia-Mathematics-Applications/dp/0521065674/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1435337437&sr=8-1-fkmr0&keywords=Finite+Fields+by+R.+Lidl+and+H.+Niederreiter

- Topics in Polynomials of One and Several Variables and Their Applications: A Legacy of P.L.Chebyshev by Th. Rassias and H. Srivastava

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Topics-Polynomials-Several-Variables-Applications/dp/9810206143/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1435337478&sr=8-1&keywords=Topics+in+Polynomials+of+One+and+Several+Variables+and+Their+Applications%3A+A+Legacy+of+P.L.Chebyshev

For some papers and notes on their relations to finite fields:

- Factoring Dickson polynomials over finite fields by M. Bhargava and M. Zieve

http://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~zieve/papers/manjul.pdf

- Reversed Dickson polynomials over finite fields by X. Hou, G. Mullen, J. Sellers, and J. Yucas

http://ac.els-cdn.com/S1071579709000525/1-s2.0-S1071579709000525-main.pdf?_tid=12fa649e-1c24-11e5-8176-00000aacb361&acdnat=1435337876_e6802338fbe470e400c11d05eb8acc7b

- Dickson polynomials over finite fields by Q. Wang and J. Yucas

http://people.math.carleton.ca/~wang/papers/genDickson.pdf

- Value sets of Dickson polynomials over finite fields by W. Chou, J.Calderon and G. Mullen

http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022314X88900066/1-s2.0-0022314X88900066-main.pdf?_tid=3a68ae6e-1c24-11e5-bc44-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1435337943_d76731b5b36282a2b6aba0afbabfe72c

- Waring's problem in finite fields with Dickson polynomials by D. Gomez and A. Winterhof

http://personales.unican.es/gomezd/Articles/Winterhof/Waring_final.pdf

- Reversed Dickson polynomials over finite fields by X. Hou, G. Mullen, J. Sellers and J. Yucas

http://www.personal.psu.edu/jxs23/ReverseDP_2.pdf

- On modified Dickson polynomials by P. Young

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.7.8464&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: No problem buddy :)

Comment: Any suggestion as to which of these are online accessible and most pedagogic?

Comment: I have added links to those that are available online